# UICollectionView: scrollViewWillBeginDragging didn't work, when the collectionView work with a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I set the collectionView as tableHeadView of a tableView, the delegate methods: scrollViewWillBeginDragging & scrollViewDidEndDragging are working well:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = bannerVc.view;
```

Notice: collectionView is the subview of BannerViewController.view.

```
[BannerViewController.view addSubview:collectionView];
```

but when I don't directly set collectionView as tableHeaderView, neither of the 2 methods works and I cannot drag the collectionView.

```
[topView addSubview:bannerVc.view];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = topView;
```

Could anyone help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some more info regarding frame sizes of each of these views. If you can draw a sketch, that'll help too.